# Azure DevOps / C# - GetTeamProjectCollection throws error when mixing .NET Framework and .NET

Tags: c#, azure-devops, tfs, .net-5, .net-4.8

I am porting my TFS / Azure DevOps application from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 5 right now.

I was able to replace most of the queries with REST API calls.

However, I also want to **discover all local workspaces** on a machine and unfortunately there is [no REST API for that](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/tfs-rest-api-for-workspaces/184635).

Since the client library that allows the queries is [only supported for .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops#microsoftteamfoundationserverextendedclient-package-doesnt-have-netstandard-support),
I have created a separate .NET Framework project that has as its only task to determine the workspaces.

```
var collection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(Uri, new 
VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, personalaccesstoken));
var vcServer = collection.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
var loggedInUser = vcServer.AuthorizedUser;
var microsoftWorkspaces = vcServer.QueryWorkspaces(null, loggedInUser, System.Environment.MachineName);
```

Unfortunately, even when I call the first line, I get the following error message:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'System.Diagnostics.Eventing.EventProvider' from assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.'

However, if I put the same project in a separate solution that contains only .NET Framework projects, I get my workspaces as desired.

Is there a compatibility issue? What can I do to resolve the issue?

Motivated by other forum posts about similar problems, I have already tried adding the following NuGet packages, unfortunately without success:

- [Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility/6.0.0)
- [System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/6.0.0)
- [System.Net.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/4.3.4)